# How to get relation with a alias Model

Tags: php, laravel, relation

Hello i have a model named `Product` and 2 model named `ProductImage` and `ProductAttribute`

What i wish ?
I want to access to the product attribute and get they element with this:

```php
Product:with(['attribute','image','category']);
```

If i will access to the attribute laravel return me this error
 `Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'product_attributes'`

> in my `Product` Model

```php
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'description',
        'category_id',
    ];

    protected $guarded = [
        'id',
    ];

    protected $dates = [
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
    ];

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }

    public function attribute()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(ProductAttributes::class,'product_attributes');
    }
}
```

> In my `ProductAttribute` Model

```php
class ProductAttributes extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'attribute',
        'value',
        'price',
        'product_id',
        'stock'
    ];

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using laravel as REST API

Comment: why is the inverse of the many to many relationship not a many to many ? is that a pivot table? if not that is not a many to many .. and what is an alias model?

Comment: By passing `product_attributes` through the belongsToMany, you're referencing it as a pivot table between `products` and `product_attributes`, referencing the table twice. Is it a pivot table for something else?

Comment: not was not a pivot table

Comment: If i remove the second parameter i got an another error `Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'table.product_product_attributes'`

Comment: a many to many relationship requires a pivot table ... if there isn't one then you don't have a many to many, it is not a `belongsToMany` without a pivot table

Comment: This sounds more like a `hasMany` than a `belongsToMany` relationship, especially as the ProductAttribute class has a `belongsTo` relationship to Product. `belongsToMany` is an many-to-many relationship (each product has many attributes, each attribute has many products, and a pivot table sits in the middle connecting to each). `hasMany` is a one-to-many relationship, where each product has many attributes, but each attribute row belongs to only 1 product.

Comment: okay thank you i will do this

Comment: That it ! thank you !